# Removing or Adding Diagonal Borders

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is being used to empty cells:

```
Sub Southwood_Click()
Sheets("Southwood").Range("C6:C8") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("D9:F9") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("F6:J8") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("J9") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("M6:S9") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("C26:C28") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("E26:E28") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("H26:O28") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("M29") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("C52:M54") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("C75:H77") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("J75:J77") = ""
Sheets("Southwood").Range("L75:P77") = ""
MsgBox "Southwood has been cleared."
End Sub
```

I would also like to remove only diagonal borders for this line:

```
Sheets("Southwood").Range("M6:S9") = ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove All Borders: `Sheets("Southwood").Range("M6:S9").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone`

Remove only diagonal borders :

```
With Sheets("Southwood").Range("M6:S9")
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

Comment: Your first answer "Remove All Borders" does NOT remove diagonals.